# РЕГУЛЯРНЫЕ ВЫРАЖЕНИЯ MYSQL ПАРОЛЬ

Tags: mysql, база-данных, регулярные-выражения

Доброго всем времени суток! Начал изучать MySQL, и появилась необходимость создать базу данных. В ней есть столбец - пароль. И мне нужно, чтобы пароль был длиной **больше** 7 символов и в нем содержались и заглавные, и строчные буквы, а также цифры. Вроде все сделал, но MySQL выдает ошибку: `Error Code: 3819. Check constraint 'CH_Password_Citizen' is violated.`

Вот код столбца с паролем:

```
Citizen_Password varchar(32) not null
constraint CH_Password_Citizen check (length(Citizen_Password) >= 8 and Citizen_Password like '/[a-zA-Z0-9]+/')
```

Порылся в Интернете, даже зашел на генератор регулярных выражений, вроде все должно работать. Пароль для теста был - Passw0rd.

[image: Генератор регулярных выражений показывает полное соответствие]

Очень прошу Вашей помощи!

Comment: @Akina смотрел на сайте каком-то про регулярные выражения в MySQL, написано что надо использовать слэши в начале и в конце

Comment: нужно использовать [`REGEXP` или `RLIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) вместо обычного `LIKE`, без слэшей

Comment: @NowhereMan спасибо Вам огромное! очень помогли;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен! Спасибо пользователю @NowhereMan. Воспользовался RLIKE вместо обычного LIKE и убрал слэши.